# Use multiple values from the page in an assertion

Tags: cypress

I have a fairly complex test involving quite a few elements on the page, need to save the values and use them later in an assertion.

Currently I am using aliases to save the values, as per the docs recommendation. Is there a way to avoid deeply nesting like this?

For example,

```js
cy.get(selector1).invoke('val').as('alias1')
cy.get(selector2).invoke('val').as('alias2')
cy.get(selector3).invoke('text').as('alias3')
cy.get(selector4).invoke('text').as('alias4')
cy.get(selector5).invoke('text').as('alias5')
// etc

cy.get('@alias1').then((val1) => {
  cy.get('@alias1').then((val2) => {
    cy.get('@alias1').then((val3) => {
      cy.get('@alias1').then((val4) => {
        cy.get('@alias1').then((val5)=> {
          // assert values against fixture
          expect([val1, val2, val3, val4, val5]).to.deep.eq(myFixture)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an alias, a property of the same name is also added to the test context.

You can use the function syntax to access "this" context, and read the values in a single callback at the end of the test.

```js
cy.get(selector1).invoke('val').as('val1')
cy.get(selector2).invoke('val').as('val2')
cy.get(selector3).invoke('text').as('val3')
cy.get(selector4).invoke('text').as('val4')
cy.get(selector5).invoke('text').as('val5')

cy.then(function() {
  const actual = [this.val1, this.val2, this.val3, this.val4, this.val5]
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(myFixture)
})
```